# How to add domain for Oauth2 to Google Dev Console

Tags: oauth-2.0

Last year I implemented Oauth2 for users of our app to sign in via Google, obtaining the client ID and configuring multiple permitted URLs via the Google Dev Console at `https://console.developers.google.com/project/<our-project-id>/apiui/credential?authuser=0`.

I now need to add another URL to the list, but the UI for the Google Dev Console has changed. Using the new UI, I don't understand how to view the URLs I already configured, and I don't understand how to add another. The documentation I've found describes adding stuff such as credentials and domains, but I don't want to click anything until I understand it better because I can't risk breaking the production app, which relies on the existing setup I established with the old Google Dev Console. In particular, I don't think I should add or change anything until I can at least see the configuration data I previously created.

I'd appreciate info on how to view my existing configuration data, either by somehow accessing the old UI or by clicking the appropriate controls in the new one. From there I'll hopefully be able to figure out how to add another URL.

By the way, the URL I want to add is a proxy server for using "ionic serve" (`http://10.0.0.15:8100/app/oauth_redirect`) if that's relevant to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can click on Credentials link in the left side menu and then click on you app. shown as hyperlink. and you will get options to add more URL to redirect uri list or to authorized uri list and you will be able to see your old configured url as well. See below screen shots to understand more.
[image]

[image]